# Get Tweets by Geolocation using twython

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm trying to search tweets by geo-location. I'm trying to get tweets in New York using:

```
twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

geocode = "42.3482° N, 75.1890° W"

search_results = twitter.search_geo(count=10,geocode=geocode)

   try:
       for tweet in search["statuses"]:
       print(tweet ['text'])
```

it returns an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\M Tools\Twython\My works\new.py", line 18, in <module>
    search_results = twitter.search_geo(count=10,geocode=geocode)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twython-3.2.0-py3.4.egg\twython\endpoints.py", line 818, in search_geo
    return self.get('geo/search', params=params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twython-3.2.0-py3.4.egg\twython\api.py", line 263, in get
    return self.request(endpoint, params=params, version=version)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twython-3.2.0-py3.4.egg\twython\api.py", line 257, in request
    api_call=url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twython-3.2.0-py3.4.egg\twython\api.py", line 198, in _request
    retry_after=response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Reset'))
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 400 (Bad Request), You must provide valid coordinates, IP address, query, or attributes.
```

Answer (score 0):

The geocode parameter should be similar to the following in the eventual Twitter search call:

```
41.8734,-70.6394,5mi
```

According to the call in the Twitter API console (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console)

> Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given
>   latitude/longitude. The location is preferentially taking from the
>   Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile. The
>   parameter value is specified by "latitude,longitude,radius", where
>   radius units must be specified as either "mi" (miles) or "km"
>   (kilometers). Note that you cannot use the near operator via the API
>   to geocode arbitrary locations; however you can use this geocode
>   parameter to search near geocodes directly. A maximum of 1,000
>   distinct "sub-regions" will be considered when using the radius
>   modifier.

Answer (score 0):

In [Twython](https://twython.readthedocs.org/), the method `search_geo` is used to find `place_id` for 'places' that are within radius of the provided geolocation.  You need to use the `search` method like so:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError


app_key = 'your_app_key'
app_secret = 'your_app_secret'
oauth_token = 'your_oauth_tokem'
oauth_token_secret = 'your_oauth_secret'

twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

geocode = '42.3482,75.1890,1mi' # latitude,longitude,distance(mi/km)

search_results = twitter.search(count=10, geocode=geocode)

try:
    for tweet in search_results['statuses']:
        print (tweet['text'])
except TwythonError as e:
    print(e)
```